# Restart d3 simulation on user input from range slider

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout, d3-force-directed

I am building a "spring" using the [d3-force](https://github.com/d3/d3-force) layout. I want to manipulate it's properties like "strength" and "distance" via user input. For that I am currently using an "input range slider". For better understanding I set up a working draft on codepen where this question is related to: http://codepen.io/bitHugger/pen/XNqGNE?editors=1010

The HTML:

```
<input id="strengthElem" step="0.1" type="range" min="0" max="2"/>
```

I wanted to do the event handling something along like this:

```
let strengthElem = window.document.getElementById('strengthElem');
let strength;

strengthElem.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  strength = strengthElem.value;
  console.log('strength', strength);
}, false);
```

Now I would like to restart or recalculate the d3.simulation object when some interaction happens with the range slider. This is my current simulation:

```
let simulation = d3.forceSimulation().nodes(nodes)
    .force("link", d3.forceLink()
        .id(function(d) { return d.index; })
        .strength(function(d) { return 2; })
        .distance(function(d) { return 2; }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody());
```

For the strength and the distance the values are currently hard coded.I would like to change it to e.g.:

```
.strength(function(d) { return strength; })
.distance(function(d) { return distance; })
```

I tried to setup a d3.call().on() function but could not get it working. I wonder how I can manipulate the simulation based on unser input, that happens outside of the force() function / outside of the svg container.

Sadly I can't get something working and I don't know how to setup a proper d3 event listener that reacts on the input button and then recalculates the force layout based on the changed values. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of creating a link force in-place without keeping a reference to the force, you should first create the force and just pass the reference to the simulation. That way, you are later on able to manipulate the force according to your sliders' values:

```
// Create as before, but keep a reference for later manipulations.
let linkForce = d3.forceLink()
  .id(function(d) { return d.index; })
  .strength(2)
  .distance(2);

let simulation = d3.forceSimulation().nodes(nodes)
  .force("link", linkForce)
  .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody());
```

When registering the event handlers on the sliders you may also want to use `d3.select()` for ease of use, and assign the functions using [`selection.on()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_on).

```
d3.select('#strengthElem')
  .on('click', function() {
    // Set the slider's value. This will re-initialize the force's strenghts.
    linkForce.strength(this.value);   
    simulation.alpha(0.5).restart();  // Re-heat the simulation
  }, false);

d3.select('#distanceElem')
  .on('click', function(evt) {
    // Set the slider's value. This will re-initialize the force's strenghts
    linkForce.distance(this.value);
    simulation.alpha(0.5).restart();  // Re-heat the simulation
  }, false);
```

Within the handler functions `this` points to the actual DOM element, whereby allowing to easily access the slider's value. The link force's parameters may now be updated using the previously kept reference. All that is left to do, is to re-heat the simulation to continue its calculations.

Have a look at this snippet for a working demo:

```js
'use strict';

var route = [[30, 30],[192, 172],[194, 170],[197, 167],[199, 164],[199, 161],[199, 157],[199, 154],[199, 150],[199, 147],[199, 143],[199, 140],[200, 137],[202, 134],[204, 132],[207, 129],[207, 126],[200, 200]];

let distance = 1;
let createNode = function(id, coords) {
  return {
    radius: 4,
    x: coords[0],
    y: coords[1],
  };
};

let getNodes = (route) => {
  let d = [];
  let i = 0;
  route.forEach(function(coord) {
    if(i === 0 || i === route.length-1) {
      d.push(createNode(i, coord));
      d[i].fx = coord[0];
      d[i].fy = coord[1];
    }
    else {
      d.push(createNode(i, coord));
    }
    ++i;
  });
  return d;
};

let getLinks = (nodes) => {
  let next = 1;
  let prev = 0;
  let obj = [];
  while(next < nodes.length) {
    obj.push({source: prev, target: next, value: 1});
    prev = next;
    ++next;
  }
  return obj;
};

let force = function(route) {
  let width = 900;
  let height = 700;
  let nodes = getNodes(route);
  let links = getLinks(nodes);

  d3.select('#strengthElem')
    .on('click', function() {
      linkForce.strength(this.value);   // Set the slider's value. This will re-initialize the force's strenghts
      simulation.alpha(0.5).restart();  // Re-heat the simulation
    }, false);

  d3.select('#distanceElem')
    .on('click', function(evt) {
      linkForce.distance(this.value);  // Set the slider's value. This will re-initialize the force's strenghts
      simulation.alpha(0.5).restart();  // Re-heat the simulation
    }, false);

  let linkForce = d3.forceLink()
    .id(function(d) { return d.index; })
    .strength(2)
    .distance(2);

  let simulation = d3.forceSimulation().nodes(nodes)
    .force("link", linkForce)
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody());

  let svg = d3.select('svg').append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height);

  let link = svg.append("g")
      .attr('class', 'link')
    .selectAll('.link')
    .data(links)
    .enter().append('line')
      .attr("stroke-width", 1);

  let node = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("r", function(d) { return d.radius; })
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return '#fabfab'; });

  simulation.nodes(nodes).on("tick", ticked);
  simulation.force("link").links(links);

  function ticked() {
    link
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
    node
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  }
};

force(route);
```

```css
.link {
    stroke: #777;
    stroke-width: 2px;
}

.links line {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: 0.6;
}

.nodes circle {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<div>Strength <input id="strengthElem" step="0.1" type="range" min="0" max="2"/></div>
<div>Distance <input id="distanceElem" step="1" type="range" min="0" max="50"/></div>

<svg style="width: 900; height: 700;"></svg>
```

I have also updated the [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LbrYrv) accordingly.

Comment: Kudos! Works like a charm. Thank you. Small thing to add: You could use d3.select("#strengthElem").on("input", function() {});  instead of "click" for the event handling. That way you don't have to release the button in order to manipulate the input. More smooth experience

Comment: @bitHugger Agreed. I also noticed that, but decided to keep the changes to your original code as non-intrusive as possible.

Comment: Wouldn't the change in strength from user input affect distance since linkForce already has distance set to 2 ? 
How do you change one particular value while keeping other attributes same after restart?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do is is removing the contents of the svg and re-drawing it with your desired constants.

I didn't understand where you got stuck because I only changed few lines like you said in your question.

Inside your click handlers I cleared the contents of the svg and called the "draw" function:

```
strengthElem.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  strength = strengthElem.value;
  console.log('strength', strength);
  d3.select('svg').selectAll("*").remove();
  force(route);
}, false);
```

Moved your config variables to a global scope:

```
var distance = 1;
let distElem = window.document.getElementById('distanceElem');
let strengthElem = window.document.getElementById('strengthElem');
var strength = strengthElem.value;
distance = distElem.value;
```

And just like you've said I've changed to return parameters:

```
 .strength(function(d) { return strength; })
 .distance(function(d) { return distance; }))
```

Full example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ObZYLo?editors=1010

Comment: Thanks for helping me! I'm on my very first project with d3 and I think I got lost in dozens of examples, searching for an example that would solve my problem. I was searching through the [forces docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-force) on github, looking for something like an d3 event handler which could do something like simulation.restart(). After hours of search I thought that this problem can't be that hard and I thought that I was missing something out :).

Comment: maybe there should be a better solution, regarding this [Tweet](https://twitter.com/mbostock/status/806590114050625537) from Mike Boststock. He says removing the nodes is something you never wanna do. Is there a way to modify the strength of the force inside of the simulation object so we don't need to remove the nodes, recalculate, and then add them back to the svg?

Comment: @bitHugger wow :D Check altocumulus's answer, seems that's the way to go :)