# Modifying Node color in Force Layout based on Color Picker

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to modify the color of some nodes in the force layout using a color picker.

I haven't found any examples of how to modify the elements within the force layout without the events being triggered within/by those elements.

[This example](https://bl.ocks.org/almsuarez/2f7219a4f52b572a3ca7da91a25681f9) is updating the layout with buttons, but is only changing the data that is passed, and then updating the graph. The data I am using contains a "group" which determines the color, which is defined in the JS. Therefore updating the data is not an option, however updating the variable doesn't work either.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41023823/restart-d3-simulation-on-user-input-from-range-slider) asks about updating forces/attributes of the simulation itself rather than its elements and the solution here did not work for me as reheating the simulation does not pick up the changed colors.

```
var cp = document.getElementById("useCasePicker");
cp.value = useCaseColor;
cp.addEventListener("change", updateColor, false);    

function updateColor(event)
{
    useCaseColor = event.target.value;
    update();
}
```

This is what I've tried to do (with update() function redrawing the graph with any new inputs) but the nodes that already exist, which I want to change, are skipped over as they already exist.

I also tried doing it this way (where node is the `<g>` element containing all circles) -

```
node.selectAll("circle").style("fill", useCaseColor);
```

This also did not work for changing the color -

```
node.selectAll("circle").remove();
label.selectAll("text").remove();
update();
```

I'm guessing I could do something like a `newColor` flag that the event sets, and when that is true, trigger an event off the nodes themselves somehow, but I assume there is a better way to do it.

This is how the nodes are defined in the `update()` function.

```
node = node.data(config.nodes, d => d.id);
    node.exit().remove();
    node = node.enter().append("circle")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .attr("r", function (d) {
                switch(d.group)
                {
                    case "use case":
                        return useCaseRad;
                    case "data service":
                        return dataServRad;
                    case "source":
                        return sourceRad;
                }
            })
            .attr("fill", function (d) {
                switch(d.group)
                {
                    case "use case":
                        return useCaseColor;
                    case "data service":
                        return dataServColor;
                    case "source":
                        return sourceColor;
                }
            })
            .attr("stroke", "black")
            .call(d3.drag()
            .on("start", dragstarted)
            .on("drag", dragged)
            .on("end", dragended))
            .on("mouseover", mouseOver)
            .on("mouseout", mouseOut)
            .merge(node);
```

I can provide more of the code if need be but I know everything with the graph works fine, I just want to be able to update the color without having to destroy the whole graph and re-draw it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to destroy the graph - simply put your fill method call after merge.

```
.merge(data)
.attr("fill", function (d) {
      switch(d.group) {
         case "use case":
             return useCaseColor;
         case "data service":
             return dataServColor;
         case "source":
             return sourceColor;
      }
})
```

merge allows you to work with both initial & enter selections, so you can update it correctly.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you! In all honesty I had no idea what merge did and just included it based on example I'd seen for adding/removing nodes. Appreciate the help.

Comment: `node = node.data(config.nodes, d => d.id)` represents UPDATE selection, the `node = node.enter()` - ENTER selection, which may append nodes according to data array, `merge` allows you to modify both ENTER + UPDATE. See https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#selections-d3-selection for details